# How do I search a file for a pattern, then extract part of the pattern or supply a default if the pattern does not exist?

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, control-flow

I'm trying to write a script that searches through a pre-made list of running processes across a series of machines. I'm specifically looking for rsyslogd running on those devices, and attempting to find what configuration file they're using (if not using the default /etc/rsyslog.conf).

Right now I'm successfully searching through the machines with this for loop:

```
for root_file in $TARGET_DIR/RESULTS*/ps_results; do
    grep rsyslogd $root_file | awk '{s = ""; for (i = 15; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s}'
done
```

And it'll return a list like

```
# get_configs $TARGET_DIR/
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
/sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -f /usr/syslog.conf
...
```

But what I want is a list that shows the IP address of the machine that is being checked (which is in the * of the RESULTS* of the script as-is) followed by just the path to the configuration file, like so:

```
# get_configs $TARGET_DIR/
172.16.10.1     /etc/syslog.conf
172.16.10.2     /etc/syslog.conf
172.17.5.245    /usr/syslog.conf
...
```

I'll be taking this list and parsing through the files and finding any additional configuration files that they might link to with the `$IncludeConfig` directive, but I've got to get through cleaning up my list of files first.

The mental block I'm hitting is testing for the `-f` option following rsyslogd. Since rsyslogd doesn't require `-f` and it runs with the default /etc/rsyslog.conf, how do I handle testing for the option and extracting the path following it or supplying a default?

I considered using `sed` or `cut` to isolate ' -f /path/to/file' and return /etc/rsyslog.conf on an empty result, but I'm not managing to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing we have the following input files

```
$ grep . */ps_results
RESULTS-172.16.10.1/ps_results:/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
RESULTS-172.16.10.2/ps_results:/sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
RESULTS-172.17.5.245/ps_results:/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -f /usr/syslog.conf
$
```

Then how about

```
$ awk '/rsyslogd/{gsub("^.*RESULTS-","",FILENAME);gsub("/ps_results","",FILENAME);b="/etc/rsyslog.conf";for(a=0;a++<NF;){if($a=="-f"){b=$(a+1)}};printf "%-15s%s\n",FILENAME,b}' RESULTS*/ps_results
172.16.10.1     /etc/rsyslog.conf
172.16.10.2     /etc/rsyslog.conf
172.17.5.245    /usr/syslog.conf
$
```

Same code, annotated+formatted:

```
awk '/rsyslogd/ {
   # strip everything up to (and including) RESULTS- from the filename
   gsub("^.*RESULTS-","",FILENAME)
   # strip the /ps_results from the filename
   gsub("/ps_results","",FILENAME)
   # set the default rsyslog conf file
   b="/etc/rsyslog.conf"
   # look for a -f parameter: if found, grab conf file
   for(a=0;a++<NF;){
     if($a=="-f") {
       b=$(a+1)
     }
   }
   # print the ip addr and conf file
   printf "%-15s%s\n",FILENAME,b
}' RESULTS*/ps_results
```

Comment: This was perfect. `gsub` seems like a useful tool for a lot of what I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your existing awk like this (this is a contrived self-contained example):

```
awk '{ s=$0; 
       if (match($s, / -f [^ ]+/)) { 
         print substr($s, RSTART+4, RLENGTH-4) 
       } 
       else 
          print "/etc/syslog.conf" 
     }' < input
```

This asks if the string `$s` contains the regular expression "(space) -f (space) (one or more non-space characters)"; if so, then print the substring that matched the regular expression, offset over by 4 characters (and correspondingly shortened by 4 characters), to account for the (space) `-f` (space).  If `$s` does *not* contain the above regular expression, print the default syslog.conf path.

The above code would go at the end of your existing awk script, replacing the `print s` portion (and, of course, not reassigning `s=$0` -- that's just there so I had data to work with).